# Selecting values from named table object if one of the names is <NA>

Tags: r

## Vector

Using the code below I'm generating my `table` object:

```
vec <- c(rep(1, 10),
         rep(5, 5),
         4,
         3,
         rep(NA, 3))

table(vec, useNA = "always") -> res
```

## Selecting values

Following object names:

```
>> names(res)
[1] "1" "3" "4" "5" NA
```

I select desired values:

```
>> res["3"]
3 
1 
>> res["5"]
5 
5
```

### Problem

This does not work for the last **`<NA>`** column:

```
<NA> 
  NA 
>> res["NA"]
<NA> 
  NA 
>> res[`NA`]
Error in NextMethod() : object 'NA' not found
```

## Side notes

I can get the correct results using column position:

```
>> res[length(res)]
<NA> 
   3
```

but I'm not interested in this I want to call the `<NA>` column by its name, how to do it?

Comment: That `NA` in its names is telling you that it has no name, and thus can't be selected by it. You could give it a name, e.g. a string `"NA"`, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is not available (NA). Try naming it something, perhaps "NA".

```
names(res)[is.na(names(res))]<-"NA"
> res[["NA"]]
[1] 3
```

or

```
res[is.na(names(res))]
```

Comment: Thanks; it’s interesting as the purpose of using *useNA* implies adding NAs as a category. Probably easier I could also get index of the column by checking which one has no name.